Achieving Precise 10-Minute Shutdowns for VLC Player
I need VLC player to shut down every 10 minutes, so I used this command: vlc -I {camAddress} --run-time=600 vlc://quit. However, it's not shutting down exactly after 10 minutes. I suspect this is because it takes about 5-10 seconds for it to connect to the IP camera initially. Therefore, the actual play time of VLC player is 600 seconds plus the initial connection time, which isn't exactly 10 minutes. I need VLC player to only run for the exact duration.

My ultimate goal is to show users their CCTV on a webpage and start recording when they press the record button. It's difficult to manage because the VLC player unexpectedly terminates after running for a long time. Therefore, I automatically repeat the streaming and recording processes every 10 minutes. My IP camera has a maximum of 2 concurrent connections. So, if the previous process hasn't properly ended and the next session starts, the recording or streaming processes may not run correctly.
